# How do Canon 600D and 650D compare with respect to focus points types?

Tags: focus, focus-point-selection, action

My photographic style is action, and according to a website that I read I need at least 9 focus points to get better photos.

I'm considering getting a Canon EOS 650D, but it turns out that it has only 2 focus points, but has 9 cross type focus points, whereas the Canon EOS 600D has 9 focus points but only one cross type focus points.

Which is the better choice, and is the difference in the types of the focus point technology relevant?

Comment: Stop reading that website. @Guffa has the right answer to this question but you need to ask a different question to find out what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Cross type focus points are slightly better than horisontal/vertical focus points.

A cross type focus point is basically a horisontal and a vertical focus point in one.

The only problem what you would have with focus points that are not the cross type, is that they have problem focusing on patterns that are horisontal or vertical, depending on their orientation. Mostly what you focus on isn't a pattern like that, so you will rarely notice any difference.

Answer (score 5):

Both the Canon 600D and the 650D have 9 focus points:

- the central focus point of the Canon 600D is cross-type, the others are not
- all the 9 focus points of the Canon 650D are cross-type.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a list.

Comment: It probably would have been better as a comment, but clarifies something the OP said.

Comment: I think it's a fine answer as it very simply clarifies the essential problem in the question. A little more explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This list is an answer.

Answer (score 2):

A "cross type" point is simply a specialized type of autofocus point.  Cross type AF points provide more accurate autofocus.

Both the 600d and 650d have 9 focus points.  The difference is that while the 650d only uses the more accurate "cross type" points.

*Details*:

The term "cross point" indicates that the focus point works in 2 dimensions instead of just one.  Many cameras use focus points that only use horizontal data to decide if the image is focused, but a cross point makes the decision by analyzing the data in 2 dimensions.

This difference allows for higher accuracy in certain situations.  One example would be where the subject is striped.  If the single dimension AF point is in the same direction as the striping, then it will not be able to detect the striping, but a cross type point would also be analyzing perpendicular to the stripes at the same time, so it would be able to detect the stripes.

Answer (score 2):

My photographic style is ACTION, and I need at least 9 focus points to get better photos, **at least, that's what a website said**

How many AF points do **you** use on the camera you have now? And which ones do you use? If you only use the center point (as I do) then it doesn't really matter if all the others are cross type, double cross type, or whatever. If you use all the points (even if not always at the same time) then it may be worthwhile to invest in a camera with a better AF sensor.

Keep in mind that not all AF points are usable with certain lenses. The center AF point will alwawys be usable, but if you have a small maximum aperture lens (not what you have your lens set to, but what the max is of the lens because it is wide open until the shutter is used) and/or use an extension tube then your outer AF points won't work on some cameras.